# jquery raty star size attribute does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css, size

I am trying to use jquery.raty.js and jquery.raty.min.js but I want to make big the stars and it does not work. I've change the size in jquery.raty.js and in this function inside the script.

I've got this plugin here:

http://wbotelhos.com/raty

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.star1').raty({
        cancel: true,
        score: 0,
        half: true,
        size: 22,
        path: 'img',
        click: function (score1, evt) {
            $('input.valor').val(score1);
        }
    });
});
```

I want the star in 22 or 24 pixels but its size is always 16.

Thank you

Comment: Where's the `$` in front of `('.star1')` in your code?

Comment: and `});` at the end of your code.

Comment: Sorry I've forgotten the start and the end of the function here when I copied it. The stars in my web work, the problem is only the size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and for me it was the browser's cache memory... It didn't work until I put in the function this attribute "single:true,"

```
$('#star').raty({
  cancel   : true,
  cancelOff: 'cancel-off-big.png',
  cancelOn : 'cancel-on-big.png',
  half     : true,
 ->>>>> single   : true,
  size     : 24,
  starHalf : 'star-half-big.png',
  starOff  : 'star-off-big.png',
  starOn   : 'star-on-big.png'
});
```

and then I could see one of them in big size. then I thought that maybe it was the cache.. and it was.

Try it, maybe is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot `$` sign in front of your code, and `});` at the end. Also, maybe you should try to start your code on the page load with the `.ready()` function.

So, code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.star1').raty({
        cancel: true,
        score: 0,
        half: true,
        size: 22,
        path: 'img',
        click: function (score1, evt) {
            $('input.valor').val(score1);
        }
    });
});
```

---

**EDIT**

Raty plugin has an [**example**](http://wbotelhos.com/raty#size) for changing size of stars. In order to set bigger size, you must have proper images for bigger stars. From site: *The size in pixel of the icon you will to use.*

```
$('#star').raty({
  cancel   : true,
  cancelOff: 'cancel-off-big.png',
  cancelOn : 'cancel-on-big.png',
  half     : true,
  size     : 24,
  starHalf : 'star-half-big.png',
  starOff  : 'star-off-big.png',
  starOn   : 'star-on-big.png'
});
```

You can try also with `path` property, but check if that path is proper.

Comment: Sorry I've forgotten the start and the end of the function here when I copied it. The stars in my web work, the problem is only the size.

Comment: I already did it, I have the images in 22px, but thank you.and I cant create them with  #star because I use more stars..thank you